# How to convert acceleration in g to speed velocity in meter /s

Tags: homework-and-exercises, measurements, speed

I'm working on an inertial measurement unit with some MEM'S component. I want to retrieve data on a micro-controller. I have 3-axis accelerometer sensor. however I want retrieve data in $mg$ ( $g=9.81$ $m/s^2$ so $mg = 0.001g = 0.00981m/s^2$) .

I just would like to calculate velocity in $meters/s$ .

how can i do that?

Comment: What were you measuring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By integrating acceleration over time.
$$v(t) = \int_{t_0}^t a(t') \mathrm{dt'} +v(t_0)$$

The principle of relativity tells us, there is no experiment/measurement one can conduct to determine if one's moving with a constant velocity, because: moving with respect to what? There is no absolute restframe.